# At a high level, how does PhoneRTC work?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webrtc, phonertc

Let's start with basics for context.

PhoneRTC is a WebRTC implementation for Cordova apps.

That means Cordova apps can access a WebRTC API.

### What is WebRTC?

Ok, let's reverse for a second. WebRTC is a standard, right? Browsers then choose to implement it or not. So Chrome implements it, meaning I can build a WebRTC app in js, roll it out in Chrome, and it'll work. If I roll out the same app on OSX Safari it won't work. Ok that makes sense.

### What are Cordova apps?

Cordova apps are web apps running in web views wrapped in native apps. So, a Cordova iOS app will be an actual iOS native app, with some kind of web view, that web view will be running your web app.

The web view is most likely some kind of webkit instance, it's a browser like sandbox, right?

BUT, the web view does not implement WebRTC.

### What is PhoneRTC (real question)?

SO, is that what PhoneRTC does? It creates an API which adheres to the WebRTC spec, and then internally, it implements the actual guts of doing all the video/audio stuff?

So, PhoneRTC is like a WebRTC implementation the same way Chrome's WebRTC support is an implementation? Meaning it's quite a low level metal implementation?

Is that right? Or does PhoneRTC bind to some existing WebRTC implementation on the native device?

Or is my question totally non-sensical?